# How to get results from default php solr?

Tags: php, solr

Am having some trouble getting the results from my solr que using php solr
printing the results mentions SolrObject a bunch
i have no idea how to parse or loop that and i cant seem to figure it out
am aware Solarium exists but i dont really see a reason to use it as things such as simply getting the results shouldn't be needing a 3rd party script

```
$client = new SolrClient($solroptions);

$query = new SolrQuery();

$query->setQuery('row:'.term("term"));
$query->addSortField("createdon",0);
$query->setStart(0);
$query->setRows(10);

$query_response = $client->query($query);

$response = $query_response->getResponse();

print_r($response);
```

is my code and it returns stuff like SolrObject Object ( [responseHeader] => SolrObject Object ( [status] => 0 [QTime] => 2 [params] => SolrObject Objec

how do i loop thou the results of a solrobject?

Comment: [This question might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973780/ideal-way-of-dealing-with-solr-results-in-php)

Comment: nope not remotely. "var_dump($res->reponse->docs[0]);"
which was what i was looking for
return
"Notice: Undefined property: SolrObject::$reponse in"
also don't even seem to be part of the doc
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.solrobject.php
ty for trying tho

Comment: Not remotely? It shows you how to access the elements/properties of your response. Each response is different, so the `docs` part is specific to their query, not yours. A quick look into the [SolrObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.solrobject.php) documentation shows there's a method `getPropertyNames` which can be used to loop over. Since it implements `ArrayAccess`, each property can be accessed as if you were accessing an array `$res["propertyname"]`. I can show an example if you're not sure how to implement that loop.

Answer (score 0):

[SolrQueryResponse::getResponse()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.solrqueryresponse.php) always returns a [SolrObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.solrobject.php) which is why you get an output that looks like an object/class (it is an instance of a class).

`SolrObject` implements `ArrayAccess` meaning it has logic setup to allow you to access properties/values using the array syntax: `$array["key"]`.

`SolrObject` also has a method called `getPropertyNames` which returns an array that can be easily iterated on. You can use this to loop through the *current* `SolrObject`'s children/properties.

Looking at [the examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/solr.examples.php) you can see that those properties can either be a value, or another `SolrObject` instance. In the case it's another `SolrObject`, it would be best to implement some form of recursion.

With all that in mind, here's an example function that uses recursion to transform a SolrObject to an array:

```php
function solrObjectToArray($object) {
    $properties = $object->getPropertyNames();

    $array = [];
    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        $value = $object[$property];
        if ($value instanceof SolrObject) {
            $array[$property] = solrObjectToArray($value);
            continue;
        }

        $array[$property] = $value;
    }

    return $array;
}
```

To implement this in your code, you can do this:

```php
$as_array = solrObjectToArray($response);
```

Comment: If you only need the `response` field, you can pass that into the function instead `$as_array = solrObjectToArray($response["response"]);`